# Changing Workflow settings within a Workflow

Tags: workflow

I currently have my workflow start when an item is changed, however i need to turn this option off, delete some data in the list and then add new data.  When the new data is added, i want start the workflow when an item is changed again.

I see Workflow context associationin the Lookup table and wondering if i can use that to turn it workflow on or off somehow.  Any body have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would reccomend, rather than the incredibly difficult task of trying to change workflow settings on the fly, that you create a new list called "Workflow Settings" with two columns: "Title" and "Value". Create a new item in that list  with a title of "IsProcessing" (or similar), and a value of "No".

Modify your workflow so when it kicks off, it looks at the value of this item, and if it is "Yes", it terminates immediately.

When your workflow gets to the point where it's deleting and adding items, it sets the value of this to "Yes", performs the additions/deletions, then sets it back to "No".

This will achieve what you need without having to dive into dynamically modifying workflow definitions.